# Can my cable modem send a bad signal causing my server to restart?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

This is most likely the dumbest question I've posted on the Stack* network yet, but is it possible for my cable modem at my house (Linksys CM100 (biggest POS ever...)) to be sending bad signals to my server (Windows 2008 x64, SP2, Core 2 Quad @2.5Ghz, 8GB RAM) causing it to restart suddenly?

I ask because my modem has been having issues over the past couple of days, and over the past couple of days I've caught my server unexpectedly shut down and restart 5 times. The server it self is less than 3 weeks old...

20 minutes before I posted this the modem had dropped its connection and it took it roughly 15 minutes and a log full of error messages later for it to finally get a new connection (of which the modem can't quite make its mind on the signal stats still). During the time it dropped I was remote-ed (sp?) in, when I remote-ed in again after the modem came back up the server prompted me with an unexpected shutdown window.

It's too coincidental, so I figured I ask people that know more than me, a.k.a. you fine gentlemen (or ladies).

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT**

I think I caused some confusion. The server is in a data center, the modem is my home modem. I remote into the server via RDP, and like I said above nearly each time that the modem would drop in the past couple of days while I'm remote-ed in the server will BSoD and restart...

Also, if someone could show me how to read the memory dump files, I will love you forever. I asked this at ServerFault, but no-one decided to answer, perhaps someone here might:

https://serverfault.com/questions/173184/how-to-read-windows-server-2008-x64-sp2-memory-dumps

Answer (score 1):

If it is a USB modem, then it may very well be the cause of a computer restart (most likely due to a buggy driver).

You can try turning off automatic system restart on error, so you'll have a chance to take a look at the actual error message/blus screen (if there is one).

Comment: I know that the server produces a BSoD, but I am unable to read the memory dumps even with the debugging tools and symbols installed... Link to that in edit above, as well as a better explanation of the setup.

Comment: @Antoine my home network consists of 2x8 port switches -> D-Link Gaming Router -> Linksys CM100 Modem

Answer (score 0):

What bios do you have ? Do you have any choice for wake on lan or something like that ? If yes, i suggest to disable them and check what will happen.

Comment: I don't have access to the server, its in a data center, the modem in questions is the one at my house.

Answer (score 0):

Can you rule out a power blip? If you're using ethernet to connect the cable modem to the computer, then no it can't; there's TCP that it uses.

Alternatively, are you sure that you don't have a virus or that someone isn't trying to hack you? I know you're using '08, but with XP/Sasser, it would do just that. I remember that all too well.

Comment: I've considered the possibility, but have not done any scans as of yet. In retrospect, there is a higher possibility of it being a virus because I haven't put AntiVirus on the server yet because I'm on the fence on what to get (plus my finances were substantially shurnk for this month thanks to the server)... (Suggestions welcome!)

Comment: There are several free antivirus programs out there for Windows. I just got done with a contract position where AV removal was a big thing of mine, and we used AVG Free across the board. Or you could check SU.com for free AV programs: http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows